# Can a plugin manually raise another plugin's Event?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, events, hook, extends, adjusters

I have created an Adjuster which is attached to `commerce_lineItems.onPopulateLineItem`.

The discount criteria is based on validation of a completely separate coupon API, so I created a permission-less user group in order to allow my client to continue using the Commerce Discounts UI. In my adjuster, I had to override the the `matchLineItem()` method in order to bypass the `$discount->allGroups` check. I'm using Craft's `httpSession` to persist the criteria through the checkout process.

Everything works fine, however if the user adds a product to the cart and THEN authenticates, the discount doesn't get applied until they either a.) update the cart or b.) raise the `commerce_lineItems.onPopulateLineItem` event again.

I've tried adding `craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($cart)` at the end of a successful API call, however that doesn't seem to trigger the event.
Is there another event I can use that will also update the cart or can I somehow raise an already declared `CEvent`? I've tried everything I know including hitting `actionUpdateCart()` with Guzzle!

I know this is a very edge case situation, so just to (briefly) illustrate I've added a portion of my base plugin below.

```
public function init()
{
    require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $this->check_membership();
    /*
     Load Premium Member Adjusters if $is_premium_member is true
    */
    craft()->on('commerce_lineItems.onPopulateLineItem', function($event){

        $lineItem    = $event->params['lineItem'];

        if ($lineItem->purchasable instanceof Commerce_VariantModel){
            if ($this->is_premium_member) {
                $this->adjusters = [
                  599 => new WorkshopAdjuster
                ];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a plugin which uses it's own events before, I guess the way to do it would be the same for separate plugins, however this is untested for your use case.

*This should go in your plugin service*

```
// Import the event from the other plugin
Craft::import('plugins.otherPluginHandle.events.OtherPluginEvent');

/Initialise the plugins event and pass whatever is required to it.
$event = new OtherPluginEvent($this, array('request' => $request));

// Raise it.
$this->raiseEvent('OtherPluginEvent', $event);
```

Again I haven't tried this from the context of calling another plugins event, but that is what I do from a plugins own event...